# Error in installing Enthought Canopy on Ubuntu (Chromebook)

Tags: python, google-chrome, ubuntu, canopy, google-chrome-os

I recently requested a student license for Enthought Canopy. The only laptop I carry with me is my chromebook, so I decided to install Canopy so that I could program on the fly. I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed using Crouton. After installing with the 32-bit sh file, I went to open the file in the Canopy directory:

```
$ ./canopy
```

But I received the following error:

```
./bin/_python: 1: ./bin/_python: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

This is on a fresh bare-bones Ubuntu install. Researched around, I guess this is a pretty obscure problem. Is there any way that I can edit and run python using canopy on this device? Even if I have to run it without the gui, as long as I can use the canopy debugger and ipython session.

Comment: What is the CPU on your Chromebook?

Comment: It's an ARM processor. Is there a Canopy release that is ARM specific? (ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, Canopy is only available for Intel / AMD x86 architecture. See: https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204273874-Canopy-Minimum-Hardware-Requirements

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'll stick to my mac and Linux tower.